# How is `*args` parsed by CPython?

Tags: python, arguments, variadic-functions, cpython, evaluation

How does CPython, behind the scenes, evaluate expressions like

```
args = (2,3)
print(*args)
```

?

The above obviously prints `2 3`, but what is CPython doing to make that appear? . Thus can I think of the `*` operator applied to iterables as a kind of macro, that CPython when running simply replaces with the iterable contents?

**NOTE TO ALL WHO WOULD LIKE TO MARK MY QUESTION IMMEDIATELY AS DUPLICATE (AS HAPPENED IN THE PAST):** This question is not addressed by [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)
That question addresses how `*` behaves in all kinds of scenarios - I'm not interested in knowing that.
There there is also only a single mentioning of CPython (which doesn't address my concern).

I want to know **internally* how CPython treats the code pasted above. Can I think of the `*` operator applied to iterables as a kind of macro, that CPython, when running, simply replaces with the iterable contents - or is CPython doing some more complex operation when parsing `*args` in the scenario above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Unsure of what you are really expecting, but I think that [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) should bring some answers. For the rest, it cannot be a macro because Python has no macros, but is explicit in Python syntax:see 6.3.4 in [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#primaries)